# MP3 Resampling in Linux

Tags: linux, mp3, lame

Tonight I am working on my music collection. I would like to **resample a large selection** of my MP3's to 192Kb/s for my Zune. I know the obvious way to do this is a recursive function using lame to encode MP3 at 192 - but lame doesn't maintain the ID3 tags!

Does anyone know of another option **that will retain ID3 info**?

Thank you all for your time / help!

Answer (score 1):

Use Audacity's [Apply Chain](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Apply_Chain) function.

> This function is similar to a "Macro"
>   of commands which allows you to select
>   a Chain (which is a sequence of
>   commands created via Edit Chains) and
>   apply it to either the current
>   project, or to a specifically selected
>   file or group of files.

Answer (score 1):

you can use id3 tagging tools like [id3v2](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) to save those tags of your mp3 first. Just a demo to illustrate

```
for mp3 in *mp3
do
  id3v2 -l  "$mp3" | while IFS=":" read -r tag info
  do
      case "$tag" in
       TYER*)
          echo "year: $info"
          year="$info" #save year info
          ;;
       TALB*)
          echo "album: $info" #save album info
          album=$info
          ;;
      esac
  done
  lame <options> "$mp3" temp #temp is output file
  id3v2 -A "$album" -y "$year" temp
  mv temp "$mp3"
done
```